# javascript- add linebreak after inserting text in textarea

Tags: javascript, php

Here is my JavaScript code . while inserting text in textbox i want to insert line break .

```
element = element +'<div class="msg_wrap"><div class="msg_body"><ul id="chatlog"></ul>'+ msg+'<div class="msg_push" id="textmesage">dg</div></div><div class="msg_footer" ><textarea id="myTextArea" class="msg_input" rows="4" onkeypress="PushMessage(event , this);"+"\n">  </textarea></div></div>';
```

and here is my function through which i get text through chatbox.

```
function PushMessage(e , textarea)
{
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
    var text1 = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;
    var div = document.getElementById('textmesage');
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + text1;
    var div = document.getElementById('textmesage').value = "<br>";
    document.getElementById('myTextArea').value = "";
}
```

i have tried +"\n" and  +"
"+ and   in place of "
" in 2ndlast line but it dsnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've understood you well.

If you want to add line break in the text you're inserting, you can use

> < br >

, as this:

```js
function PushMessage(e , textarea) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
      var text1 = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;
      var div = document.getElementById('textmesage');
      div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<br>' + text1;
      document.getElementById('myTextArea').value = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="msg_wrap">
  <div class="msg_body">
    <ul id="chatlog"></ul>
    <div class="msg_push" id="textmesage">dg</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="msg_footer" >
    <textarea id="myTextArea" class="msg_input" rows="4" onkeypress="PushMessage(event , this);"></textarea>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: happy to hear it worked for you! you can mark my answer with the green tick if you think it resolved your question :)

Comment: yeah sure . can you please tell me one more thing that this below code is okay or not                                                                                           element = element + '<div><a href="javascript:get_message('+id+'","'+msg+');"></a></div>';

Comment: it looks good. if you have something that doesn't work and it's a different problem that the one posted in this thread, you can open another one to get help! :)

Comment: i reached to my question limit due to this question. because i am new in stack overflow